# Hashbytes MD5 syntax

Tags: hash, sql-server-2012

Why do the hashed results below differ? Shouldn't they be the same?

```
SELECT [teststring]
, SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', [teststring])), 3, 32)
, SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', 'HelloWorld')), 3, 32)
  FROM [test]
  WHERE [teststring]='HelloWorld'
```

```
HelloWorld 87434a4b7918d288dc1c1e0ca7544e77    68e109f0f40ca72a15e05cc22786f8e6
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this, it would appear that your column is storing an NVARCHAR rather than a VARCHAR (which is what you have specified your string as in your query), these are stored differently and will therefore give different results.

If you run the following query you should see that they are the same when using the same datatype (NVARCHAR):

```
SELECT [teststring]
, SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', [teststring])), 3, 32)
, SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', N'HelloWorld')), 3, 32)
  FROM [test]
  WHERE [teststring]='HelloWorld'
```